# Can't locate XML/Writer.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, perl-module

can someone help me to exclude below the error.

Thanks in advance

Can't locate XML/Writer.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/svceln/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2/x86_64-linux /home/svceln/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2 /home/svceln/usr/lib/perl5/5.16.2/x86_64-linux /home/svceln/usr/lib/perl5/5.16.2 .) at /opt/apps/tomcat_scripts/allocate_ports.pl line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/apps/tomcat_scripts/allocate_ports.pl line 7.
Error in allocating ports, server.xml cannot run`

The script i am using

```
#!/home/svceln/usr/bin/perl -w
# allocate_ports.pl

# allocate ports, create port_config.xml and write to stdout

use strict;
use XML::Writer;
use IO::File;enter code here
use File::Basename;

my ($increment) = 0;
my ($execDir) = dirname($0);

$#ARGV eq 0 or die "Usage: allocate_ports.pl server_name\n";

my ($port_read) = new IO::File ("$execDir/port_increment.txt");
if (defined $port_read) {
  while (<$port_read>) {
    chomp;
    $increment = $_;
  }
  $port_read->close() or die "Can't close port_increment.txt: $!";
} else {
  $increment = 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like `XML::Writer` isn't installed.

Comment: i just followed the below steps to install perl. anything wrong? https://perlmaven.com/download-and-install-perl

Comment: @Ragu XML::Writer is not part of perl. It must be installed separately.

Comment: XML::Writer is not a part of Perls core modules ("built in" modules that almost always follows an installation of Perl). There are many ways to install additional modules. Among others, this might be a good start: https://www.thoughtco.com/installing-perl-modules-from-cpan-2641120

Also try command: locate XML/Writer.pm
And then add this as line 2 in your program: use lib 'path'; #where path is the result of locate up to but not including the string "XML/Writer.pm" itself.

Answer (score 1):

It might be in a package, say libxml-writer-perl, assuming Debian.

apt-cache search XML::Writer gives a list of packages if your system uses apt.

Depends on how you are getting your perl modules.

Comment: That won't work here. Judging from the list of directories in `@INC` this is a custom built perl, not system perl. `cpan XML::Writer` ought to work, though.